# How to convert a String into an Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, type-conversion

I have a response coming in `string` format:

```
returnData = "1002246*9994456861#111#222*ACTIVE"
```

In need to modify that `string` data into an `object`:

```
{returnData : "1002246*9994456861#111#222*ACTIVE"}
```

The below is what I tried:

```
returnData = Object.assign({}, returnData)
```

But it throws me results in `array` for every single characters. How to convert that `string` variable into the `object`?

Comment: i think you need this `Object.assign({}, {returnData})`

Comment: @PrabhuMurthy `Object.assign()` makes this way more complicated than it needs to be. Just `{returnData}` is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create an object with the current value:

```js
returnData = "1002246*9994456861#111#222*ACTIVE"
returnData = { returnData }

console.log(returnData);
```

Answer (score 0):

To create the object you want from a string, just use object literal notation:

```
data = {
    returnData: returnData
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use `Object.keys()` method, like this:

```js
returnData = "1002246*9994456861#111#222*ACTIVE";

console.log({[Object.keys({returnData})[0]]: returnData});
```

Comment: Why make it so complicated? Just `{returnData}` creates the desired object.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That's what I think.